# NetworkManager package unable to install

Tags: centos, yum, networkmanager

Currently I'm trying to install package `NetworkManager` in `Linux 2.6.32-642.6.2.el6.i686 i686`.

When I run `yum install`, it says:

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum install NetworkManager-config-routing-rules
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, kmod
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
No package NetworkManager-config-routing-rules available.
```

May I know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try `NetworkManager-dispatcher-routing-rules`.

See: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1334876